# I am building an HTML application that uses 3D UI elements and animations. What are some tools and libraries that I might find helpful?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

So I'm planning to create a web application that uses 3-dimensional UI elements and animated transitions to create a rich user experience. What tools and libraries would you recommend that I use to make this application's development go as quickly and smoothly as possible? (three.js perhaps?)

Specifically, I'm looking for development libraries and tools that make it easy to create 3D UI elements and handle CSS transitions. I'm also interesting in including some level of support for graceful degradation, so that things don't stop working completely on older and mobile browsers.

Comment: “Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.” [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Be on the lookout for http://infamous.io (name subject to change). Small 3D demo (at time of writing), letters flying into a grid layout: http://mightydevs.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[WebGL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebGL)**:

> WebGL brings 3D graphics to the Web by introducing an API that closely
>   conforms to OpenGL ES 2.0 that can be used in HTML5 canvas elements.
>   Support for WebGL is present in Firefox 4+, Google Chrome 9+, Opera
>   12+ and Safari 5.1+.

In order to be more helpful you would need to provide more than what you would *like* to accomplish. **Specifications**, **example code**, **what you've tried** and **what you're having trouble with** are all things we like to see here to help answer your question.

What **browsers/versions** are you targeting, what technologies have you looked into and what will this be used for?  Without knowing the gory **details**, it's honestly hard for people to help.

**[Creativejs](http://creativejs.com/about/)** may be something that interests you.

**[Three.js](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/)**, as you asked about above, is a nice library as well.

There's also a nice list of many other **[here](https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/WebGL)**.

**edit:**

If that's the case then the majority of the libraries in the link above would meet your needs. I would suggest taking a good look into a few of them and trying out some tutorials.

Comment: That's more of a technology than a tool or library. I was thinking more along the lines of JS libraries and development tools.

Comment: @Ajedi32 - The links I've added should suffice in helping you find the proper library for the job.

Comment: Thanks. Really all I'm looking for are some tools that make it easy to create 3D UI elements and CSS transitions. I'm not all that concerned about targeting specific browsers, although chances are many of the prettier parts of the UI wouldn't work on older browsers. I'd probably like some level of backwards compatibility. I'll add a bit more detail to my question, but I'm not sure how much more specific I can be.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, [Dom3D](http://jlongster.com/s/dom3d/) might* be useful.

Considering that it's done with CSS3 transforms on regular DOM elements (no canvas, extensions or plugins), I think it does a wonderful job.

*If you need pixel perfect or uber-slick graphics though Dom3D might not be for you.

Comment: As far as 3d goes, I'm basically looking for a simple way to incorporate 3d elements into my application's UI. I don't need anything too complex, but I definitely want it to look good.